# Windows system restore increase automatic restore points

Tags: windows, backup, restore

After 2 days[image: Screenshot of Schedule and Restore]

you can see that the task triggered 3 times (the last one was forced to run by me) but I only have 1 restore point.

---

I've tried looking for quite some time about this but didn't find anything relevant.

I've already set task scheduler to create a restore point every 2 days, but you can only have 1 automatic restore point per week.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378724(v=vs.85).aspx

> System Restore in Windows 7 checks every day and creates a scheduled
>   restore point **if no other restore points have been created in the last
>   7 days.**

The problem is that Windows only allows 1 automatically created restore point per 7 days. You can trigger it more frequently but if there is another system restore created by task scheduler it will do nothing.

What I'd like to have is to increase the amount of scheduled restore points from 1 to 3 and if 3 are present, delete/overwrite the oldest one. To remove the restore old restore points I could use cleanmgr with parameters but that would delete all of them.

I think that I could somehow change the argument that starts the system restore, currently, it's "ExecuteScheduledSPPCreation". If I could find all the arguments for srtasks.exe that are for SystemRestore and change it to make it appear as "manual restore point".

I'm on Win 8.1 but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: *"but you can only have 1 automatic restore point per week."* ... I think you mean on its own, Windows will create a maximum of 1 restore point every 7 days. *"What I'd like to have is to increase it from 1 to 3"*...increase what? *"if 3 are present, delete/overwrite the oldest one"* Windows automatically removes old restore points once their total size exceeds the limit you set in the System Restore configuration dialog. Why do you want it based on count instead of size?

Comment: You can set how often do you want to create a restore point, by default it's set to 7 days "taskschd.msc -> Microsoft -> Windows -> SystemRestore" trigger is every week but you can change it how you like. But there is hard limitation of maximum 1 can be stored per week. No matter the maximum size of the SystemRestore. I want to have 3 restore points that are 2 days apart from each other, but you can't do that because you only can have 1 per week that is automatically created by taskschd

Comment: The source you cite does not say "there's a hard limit of 1 that can be stored per week," yet the way you've worded the question implies that's what you're positing. Please clarify that with an edit.

Comment: I think you're misreading the guidance.  It automatically creates one if there has not been any others in 7 days, but you can create others.